# git branch merging details

Tags: git, merge, branch

I noticed the following branch merged to master branch. I have a DEV and Master stream. This branch was merged to DEV but some how also found in master when I review master by issuing `git log origin/master` command.

```
   commit 8123e23e3322b02b9871fea4d152e07ec5b9361443520d2
   Merge: e4d499a 5ef2bd6
   Author: devuser<user1@mydomain.org>
   Date:   Fri Jul 01 16:24:53 2013 -0700

   Merge branch 'my_branch' into dev
```

Is there a way to figure out how this get to master branch?

Example:

```
User A run the following:
  git checkout master
  git checkout -b my_branch
  git add .
  git commit -m "my work done"
  git checkout dev
  git merge my_branch
  git push


User B run the following:
  git checkout my_branch
  git pull
  git checkout master
  git merge my_branch
  git push
```

**In git log, can we find out if User B did the merge or user A ?**

Please the attached picture. It says "Merge branch "my_branch" into Dev" but actually it is merging to master. Am I reading this right?

[image]

Comment: IF you merged it to DEV and then merged DEV to master, your other branch will also be contained in master

Comment: This is what need to figure out when and how this branch was merged to master. How can I see who did merge from DEV to MASTER? if that's what happend

Comment: `git merge-base master dev` should give you the answer. You'll probably find it in one of the recent commits

Comment: NO, it doesn't answer. it gives me a commit ID of recent merge from a user branch not dev.

Comment: To find out who did the merge, just look at the commit data

Comment: @knittl can you please provide some example. `git show [commitid]` provides detail with author name, Is that author for who did the merger as well?

Comment: _Yes_, the author of the merge commit is the author of the merge, is the user who did that merge and committed it.

Comment: thanks @knittl In my question above with commit data that shows the devuser for this merger, right? also in the picture show merger with master but why it says "into dev"

Comment: @Saltron: You do know, that in Git, "branch" can mean two things? The _actual commits_ that are in a _line of development_ or a _label_ that is tucked onto a commit and updates when a new commit is made (the green boxes you see in your screenshot). The label always points to the most recent commit in a certain branch (the _tip_). Labels can be freely moved around and set to any commit you like. You can arrive in your situation via two ways: someone branched off master of dev, or master was fully contained (already merged) in dev, so master was fast-forwarded during the next merge.

Comment: Got it. thank you so much. it is clear now. Please put your response as answer so I can mark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iin Git, "branch" can mean two things. The actual commits that are in a line of development or a label that is tucked onto a commit and updates when a new commit is made (the green boxes you see in your screenshot).

The label always points to the most recent commit in a certain branch (the tip). Labels can be freely moved around and set to any commit you like. You can even have multiple labels point at the exact same commit.

You can arrive in your situation via two ways: someone branched off master of dev, or master was fully contained (already merged) in dev, so master was fast-forwarded during the next merge.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$ git reflog` to see a detailed history of whatever went down in your repository.

Look at http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/02/09/reflog-your-safety-net.html & https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reflog.html for more info.

Comment: this is good. its provide detail on the local activity but my question is on this particular merge detail that went to master by somebody but not sure how. how do find this out?